# Android device is not recognize attached USB

Tags: android, usb, ftdi, usb-otg

I'm making application that needs to comunicate with device baseed on FTDI FT230X chip. My applications runs fine and communicate with device perfectly. But on some other mobile phones or tables this attached USB device is not recognized even if they have support for OTG and USBHost mode. All testing devices are running Android 4.0 or above. I'm little bit confused because I can't determine reason why on some devices works and on other doesn't. I have also tried on rooted with custom ROMs and the problem is the same. Does anybody have an idea or experience to give me some hint what to do or to try?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is at your usb device. Unfortunately no one could help you out with this. Try changing the usb on the go it works fine sometimes sometime

Answer (score 1):

It looks that FT230X is a USB->UART chip, which requires corresponding driver on the host. Some phones/tablets have this driver (like yours), but some don't.

Comment: This drivers are provided by Android OS or for example HTC decide to implement or not implement driver support their Android OS distribution for mobile phones? Because, as far as i know, the kernel is same for all? Isn't it?

Comment: The kernel is the same but different phones have different HW, so drivers are all different.